# Simple jdbc queryForList taking approx 3 seconds to execute

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-boot

```
title=jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT distinct title from UD_REGGRESSION where delete_flag='N'",String.class);
```

The above query is taking around 3 to 4 seconds to execute with only 21 records being fetched. In Toad it takes around 500 to 600 ms to execute the same query. Why is there so much difference in time ?

Class were configuration is done.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oracle")
public class OracleConfiguration {
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private String url;
    @NotNull
    private String decryptionKey;

    public String getDecryptionKey() {
        return decryptionKey;
    }

    public void setDecryptionKey(String decryptionKey) {
        this.decryptionKey = decryptionKey;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setURL(url);
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void decrypt() {
        this.password = DecryptUtility.decrypt(this.password,
                this.decryptionKey);
    }
}
```

Can someone suggest any improvements that can be done to get a better response time ?

Comment: Why.. Well firs you are comparing apples and oranges. In java you don't use a connection pool, so when doing a query first a connection needs to be created, transaction started etc. which is slow. Next you don't just create and execute a query generally when retrieving results you also convert them into objects, which also adds time. In short use a connection pool and don't compare the execution time in toad with the total execution time in a java program.

Comment: Indexing the `delete_flag` column _might_ help to make the query faster, depending on the distribution of data in the table.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Thanks for the quick response. Could you please help me out in understanding what exactly you mean when you say to use a connection pool. From my understanding a connection pool is basically a cache which helps us in future database calls. Is OracleDataSource not taking care of that through setImplicitCachingEnabled. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: No it isn't... A connection pool is a pool of connection. The `OracleDataSource` (AFAIK) isn't that or if it is you haven't configured it for that.